# Cant load data when im publishing my shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a simple shiny app. The relevant code looks like this:

Server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)

    shinyServer(function(input, output){

      #Hier output je je plot, let op $myhist is iets wat je teruggeeft
      output$myhist <- renderPlot({


        df_graph <- df_test[df_test$playlist_name == input$var,]

        #Dit is gewoon een normale graph aanmaken obv graph_data
        g <- ggplot(df_graph, aes(x=key, y=value)) + geom_boxplot()
        print(g)
      })
    })
```

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  #maken sample data

  #setwd("~/shiny_apps/echonest"),
  df_test <- read.csv("df_echonest.csv", stringsAsFactors = F),
  listIDs <- df_test$playlist_name,
  #outlinen title
  titlePanel(title = "This is the title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      #Here you enter the var that you would like to use to filter the data shown in the graph
      selectInput("var", "Select the eventID", choices = listIDs),
      br(),
      sliderInput("amount of fluctuation", "Integer:",
                  min=0, max=30, value=0)
    ),

    mainPanel(("Personal information"),
              plotOutput("myhist"))
  )
))
```

All the relevant data that I need for running the app is stored in a .csv file that is also placed in the same folder and loaded using the following line in UI.R file:

```
df_test <- read.csv("df_echonest.csv", stringsAsFactors = F),
```

When I run it local it all works smooth. However when I try to deploy it using shiny and try to visit the relevant page (https://marcvanderpeet12.shinyapps.io/echonest/)I get the message:

```
Personal information Error: object 'df_test' not found
```

While the list actually loads (and that information also comes from df_test). Any thoughts where this goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to import df_echonest.csv in the server.R ,UI find it but nothing server side